# SQLAlchemy: JOIN between different databases AND using different files in a module

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mariadb, fastapi

### Stack

I am using:

- Python 3.10.x
- FastAPI 0.75.x
- SQLAlchemy 1.4.3x

### Summary

I am building a unifying FastAPI project for several legacy databases (stored back-end on MariaDB 10.3 - structure has to be retained for some legacy software).

My SQLA setup uses a databases module to do the following:

#### /databases.py

```python
import dotenv
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

import .models as models

dotenv.load_dotenv()

engines = {
    'parts': create_engine("mysql+pymysql://" + os.environ['DB_URL'] + "/parts", pool_pre_ping=True, pool_recycle=300),
    'shop': create_engine("mysql+pymysql://" + os.environ['DB_URL'] + "/shop", pool_pre_ping=True, pool_recycle=300),
    'purchasing': create_engine("mysql+pymysql://" + os.environ['DB_URL'] + "/purchasing", pool_pre_ping=True, pool_recycle=300),
    "company": create_engine("mysql+pymysql://" + os.environ['DB_URL'] + "/company", pool_pre_ping=True, pool_recycle=300),
    "auth": create_engine("mysql+pymysql://" + os.environ['DB_URL'] + "/auth", pool_pre_ping=True, pool_recycle=300),
}

DBSession = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, binds={
    # Catalogue
    models.Shop.Catalogue: engines["shop"],
    models.Shop.Sections: engines["shop"],
    models.Shop.Orders: engines["shop"],
    # ...
    # Parts
    models.Parts.Part: engines["parts"],
    models.Parts.BinLocations: engines["parts"],

    # ...
    #Purchasing
    models.Purchasing.SupplierOrder: engines["purchasing"],
    models.Purchasing.SupplierOrder: engines["purchasing"],
    # Company Data
    models.Company.Staffmember: engines["company"],
    models.Company.Suppliers: engines["company"],
    # API Auth
    models.Auth.User: engines["auth"],
    models.Auth.Privileges: engines["auth"],
})

# Dependency
def getDb():
    db = DBSession()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

It's a little laborious having to do this for every model but it does work.

As I have several dbs I thought it would be logical to create a `models` module with sub-files for each db e.g. `models.Parts`, `models.Shop`, `models.Purchase`, `models.Company`, `models.Auth` etc.

/models/**init**.py

```python
from importlib.metadata import metadata
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base

base = declarative_base()

from . import Auth, Parts, Shop, Catalogue, Purchasing, Shop
```

I can create relationships successfully by importing the `Base` object in the `__init__.py` of `models` and importing that to each sub-file. For example:

#### /models/Auth.py

```python
from . import base as Base

from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Numeric, Date, DateTime, ForeignKey, null, or_, and_

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(256), nullable=False)
    passhash = Column(String(512), nullable=False)
    email = Column(String, nullable=False)
    enabled = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    staffmember_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

    staffmember = relationship("Company.Staffmember", uselist=False)
```

#### /models/Company.py

```python
from . import base as Base

from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Numeric, Date, DateTime, ForeignKey, null, or_, and_

class Staffmebmer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'staffmembers'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.staffmember_id"), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    order = Column(Integer, default=0, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String, nullable=True)
    initial = Column(String, nullable=True)
    email = Column(String, nullable=False)
    enabled = Column(Integer, default=0, nullable=False)

    relationship("Auth.User", back_populates="staffmember")
```

The following route works just fine:

#### demo.py

```python
from fastapi import Depends

from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from .. import app, databases, models

@app.get("/api/user/{id}")
async def read_items(id: int, db: Session=Depends(databases.getDb)):
    user = db.query(models.Auth.User).filter(
        models.Auth.User.id == id
    ).first()

    user.staffmember

    return user
```

Accessing this URL returns:
**(Yes, I'm aware this isn't secure, it is for illustrative purposes only to show that the relationship functions!)**

```json
{
  "username": "mark",
  "passhash": "<my hash>",
  "enabled": 1,
  "email": "mark@demo.com",
  "id": 1,
  "staffmember_id": 5,
  "staffmember": {
    "order": 20,
    "name": "Mark",
    "email": "mark@demo.com",
    "kStaffmember": 5,
    "initial": "MB",
    "enabled": 1
  }
}
```

However, I want to use steffmember initials as a possible username, so when I qyuery for a user in my OAUTH Authorize scripts I tried to use:

```python
from ..models import Auth, Company

# 'username' is provided by the auth script from the standard username/password OAuth fields

def get_user(db: Session, username: str):
    db_user_data = db.query(Auth.User).join(Company.Staffmember).filter(
        or_(
            Auth.User.username == username,
            Auth.User.email == username,
            Company.Staffmember.initial == username
        )
    ).first()
```

and I get an Exception:

```
(pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1146, "Table 'auth.staffmembers' doesn't exist")
```

Am I going about this whole thing the right way and is there a possible way around this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone stumbles over this and needs a rational answer I couched it to the SQLAlchemy Git discussions page and got a pretty sane answer back that helped me resolve it.

https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/8027

### In summary:

- You don't need multiple engine connections to the **same MySQL/mariadb server** for different databases. You just need to start a session on one of the databases - remember it's the name of the **database** not the model or module in the Python SQA code.

##### My new databases.py:

```python
import dotenv
import os

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

import .models as models

dotenv.load_dotenv()

DBengine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://" + os.environ['DB_URL'] + "/parts", pool_pre_ping=True, pool_recycle=300)

DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=DBengine autocommit=False, autoflush=False)

# Dependency
def getDb():
    db = DBSession()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

- If you use the above style, you need to be more explicit with your `ForeignKey()` statements e.g. `ForeignKey("<db>.<table>.<field>")` so you are explicitly telling SQA which database and table to look in for every one.
- You will need to sate the name of the database name to each model as the schema e.g. add `__table_args__ = { "schema": "<database name>" }` - remember it's the name of the **database** not the model or module in the Python SQA code.

##### New /modules/Auth.py

```python
from . import base as Base

from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Numeric, Date, DateTime, ForeignKey, null, or_, and_

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users' #table is called 'users'
    __table_args__ = { "schema": "auth" } #database is called 'auth'

    id = Column(Integer, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(256), nullable=False)
    passhash = Column(String(512), nullable=False)
    email = Column(String, nullable=False)
    enabled = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
    staffmember_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)

    staffmember = relationship("Company.Staffmember", uselist=False)
```

##### New /models/Company.py

```python
from . import base as Base

from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Numeric, Date, DateTime, ForeignKey, null, or_, and_

class Staffmember(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'staffmembers' #table is called 'staffmembers'
    __table_args__ = { "schema": "company" } #database is called 'company'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("auth.users.staffmember_id"), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    # ForeignKey now needs to know the database AND table name for the field it refers to
    order = Column(Integer, default=0, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String, nullable=True)
    initial = Column(String, nullable=True)
    email = Column(String, nullable=False)
    enabled = Column(Integer, default=0, nullable=False)

    relationship("Auth.User", back_populates="staffmember")
```

Once you use this process, SQA knows to prefix the correct database name in joins and relationships and things should work fine.